# Unable to run Hangfire job in background continuously

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, background-process, hangfire, hangfire-console

We are trying to run a .Net Core Hangfire Job application in Docker container. We are able to run this application in console(foreground) but if we hit Enter button it is automatically stopped.

When we are trying to run same application in background it is not working. When we start the container the application is starting and automatically getting stopped.

Can anyone help me to run this application in background continuously using Docker, without any issues.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to provide your hangfire config and relevant code around the set-up. a generic article on hangfire and .net core can be found here https://www.changingrequirements.com/2016/11/10/hangfire-on-net-core-docker/ Maybe it's helpful, maybe not